# Copied style is null. Using StyleNotFound instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

Well, I'm experiencing some errors in Unity 2019.2.14f. For some reason, I'm having the following error:

`Copied style is null. Using StyleNotFound instead.`

The problem is related to this line: https://github.com/uta-org/uzLib.Lite/blob/82eb85bc34c804cfd392b447e97e1e92079ca10f/uzLib.Lite/Unity/Global/IMGUI/GlobalGUILayout.cs#L233

```
public string InputIO(string label, string path, FileBrowserType browserType = FileBrowserType.File, bool isEnabled = true, bool fEditor = false, int verticalSpacing = 7)
        {
            if (verticalSpacing > 0)
                GUILayout.Space(verticalSpacing);

            bool hasLabel = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(label);

            var boxStyle = MyGuiSkin?.box;
            if (hasLabel)
            {
                if (boxStyle != null)
                    GUILayout.BeginVertical(boxStyle);
                else
                    GUILayout.BeginVertical();

                //GUILayout.Label(label);
                GUILayout.Label(label, GlobalStyles.BoldCenteredLabelStyle); <===== here is the problem

                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            }
            else
            {
                if (boxStyle != null)
                    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal(boxStyle);
                else
                    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            }

            // TODO: Fix the alignment of the two labels
            GUILayout.Label(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? $"Select a {browserType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()}..." : path, GlobalStyles.CenteredLabelStyle);
            //GUILayout.Label(path ?? "Select a file...", GlobalStyles.CenteredLabelStyle); // GlobalStyles.CenteredLabelStyle --> GUI.skin.label returns null and an error

            GUI.enabled = isEnabled;
            if (GUILayout.Button("Browse...", GUILayout.MaxWidth(100)))
            {
                if (fEditor)
                {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                                var p = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanelWithFilters("Select a file", path,
                                    new[] { "Image files", "png,jpg,jpeg,bmp,gif,tif" });
                                path = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? null : p;
#endif
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MyFileBrowser == null)
                        MyFileBrowser = FileBrowser.Create(browserType);

                    path = MyFileBrowser.Open();
                }
            }
            GUI.enabled = true;

            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            if (hasLabel)
                GUILayout.EndVertical();

            if (!fEditor && MyFileBrowser != null && MyFileBrowser.IsReady())
            {
                path = MyFileBrowser.CurrentPath;
                //Debug.Log($"Setting path to '{path}'...");
            }

            return path;

            //return string.Empty;
        }
```

For some reason, `GlobalStyles.BoldCenteredLabelStyle` style and any style I created on the `GlobalStyles` is creating problems:

```
private static GUIStyle s_boldCenteredLabelStyle;

        public static GUIStyle BoldCenteredLabelStyle =>
            s_boldCenteredLabelStyle ?? (s_boldCenteredLabelStyle = new GUIStyle(DefaultLabelStyle)
            { fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold, alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter });
```

**Source:** https://github.com/uta-org/uzLib.Lite/blob/master/uzLib.Lite.ExternalCode/Unity/Global/IMGUI/GlobalStyles.cs#L506-L510

I reviewed the code from UnityEngine, and I found this:

```
        public GUIStyle(GUIStyle other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Copied style is null. Using StyleNotFound instead.");
                other = GUISkin.error;
            }
            m_Ptr = Internal_Copy(this, other);
        }
```

**Source:** https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/IMGUI/GUIStyle.cs#L81-L89

This happens when a null style is passed through the GUIStyle constructor, but as you can see I'm not doing anything of this (before using `DefaultLabelStyle` I was using `GUI.skin.label` but I removed it and I created my own style). Also, I tried to pass an empty constructor, but it's giving me errors also.

So I'm lost, I don't know what to try, any help is welcome!

**PD:** I think this could be possibly a bug... But I'm not sure.

Comment: I checked your `s_boldCenteredLabelStyle` in 2019.2.0f1. It works as it should. I guess `GlobalStyles` is somehow null. If you pass directly `s_boldCenteredLabelStyle`, it works. Correct?

Comment: You should stop using `OnGui` (IMGUI) and use the new UI system (UGUI) instead.